# How to copy datatable using LINQ to SQL if any of the field is NULL

Tags: c#, exception, datetime, linq-to-sql

I have a method which will return the datatable from LINQ to SQL

i'e

```
 public static DataTable LinqToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
   {
       DataTable output = new DataTable();
       try
       {
           PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
           foreach (var prop in properties)
           {
               output.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(
               prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
           }
           foreach (var item in source)
           {
               DataRow row = output.NewRow();
               foreach (var prop in properties)
               {
                   row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
               }
               output.Rows.Add(row);
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
       return output;
   }
```

My problem is, if any of the DateTime field is null, this methos throwing an exception as

```
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.DateTime which is a non-nullable value
```

type.

How to rectify the error. Please anybody Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about declaring the property as DateTime? . Whereever you have date time property you can change the type to DateTime? from DateTime.

You have created a column of type DateTime and you are trying to set null to the column.

Comment: Yes sir.. That is the DateTime Property of datatable in databse

Comment: In such case, the object cannot have a null value for the property. If you are expecting null value, you can change the datatype in the database to accept null values.

Comment: there is no such property in sql databse

Comment: got it with allow nulls to true. Thank you soo much